# How to compact identical repeating Else If statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, coding-efficiency

I am experimenting with simple programs that the User can navigate with basic ReadLine input. At any given time during an input, there are a couple of commands that are always accessible regardless of the circumstances, here is an example:

```
else if(input.ToLower() == "exit" || input.ToLower() == "leave")
{
    Console.Clear();
    ExitProgram.ExitProg();
    calcInput = false;
}
else if(input.ToLower() == "back" || input.ToLower() == "menu")
{
    TxtFun.CTxt("Returning to previous menu.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    calcInput = false;
    calcLoop = false;
}
else
{
    TxtFun.CTxt("Invalid input.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();

    calcInput = false;
}
```

Above are 2 If Else statements that are repeated EVERY time I ask for User Input and then check it. This gets very line heavy as I nest User Input several times.

My question is, would there be a way to compact these repeating Else If statements into a function or a separate class, in order to save time and (a lot) of space, that would be efficient to insert into an If/Else If branch?

((Bonus Points if there would be a way to contain the ever repeated "Else" at the end that returns "Invalid Input", but that is not the main question or goal.))

Comment: strategy pattern? Switch case?

Comment: start with something simple like a function - what have you tried so far?

Comment: where is `if` statement? why jump on `elseif`?

Comment: A [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) might help.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this a bit differently while implementing REPL interfaces.

Use a `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>` (in fact, I use a class that encapsulates the actual `Func` or `Action` together with a description that can be used to help with the usability of the application by generating a `help` text) with String Comparison that ignores the case and add the inputs that you are expecting into the dictionary where the object is the function that you want to execute.

This becomes self-documenting as well and you would be able to automatically create Help documentation too!

If you wish, I can quickly post an example tomorrow.
-- Adding the key pieces of the code example (from the Program.cs file) below:

A class we will use to capture the REPL Command information:

```
    class ReplCommand
    {

        public string Command { get; set; }
        public string HelpText { get; set; }
        public Action<string> MethodToCall { get; set; }
        public int HelpSortOrder { get; set; }

    }
```

This is where we define all the valid commands

```
        static void PopulateCommands()
        {
            // Add your commands here
            AddCommand(new ReplCommand
            {
                Command = "MyCommand", // The command that the user will enter (case insensitive)
                HelpText = "This is the help text of my command", // Help text
                MethodToCall = MyCommand, // The actual method that we will trigger
                HelpSortOrder = 1 // The order in which the command will be displayed in the help
            });

            // Default Commands
            AddCommand(new ReplCommand
            {
                Command = "help",
                HelpText = "Prints usage information",
                MethodToCall = PrintHelp,
                HelpSortOrder = 100
            });
            AddCommand(new ReplCommand
            {
                Command = "quit",
                HelpText = "Terminates the console application",
                MethodToCall = Quit,
                HelpSortOrder = 101
            });

        }

        static void AddCommand(ReplCommand replCommand)
        {
            // Add the command into the dictionary to be looked up later
            _commands.Add(replCommand.Command, replCommand);
        }
```

This is key parts of the program:

```
        // The dictionary where we will keep a list of all valid commands
        static Dictionary<string, ReplCommand> _commands = new Dictionary<string, ReplCommand>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create Commands
            PopulateCommands();

            // Run continuously until "quit" is entered
            while (true)
            {
                // Ask the user to enter their command
                Console.WriteLine("Please input your command and hit enter");
                // Capture the input
                string sInput = Console.ReadLine();
                // Search the input from within the commands
                if (_commands.TryGetValue(sInput, out ReplCommand c))
                {
                    // Found the command. Let's execute it
                    c.MethodToCall(sInput);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Command was not found, trigger the help text
                    PrintHelp(sInput);
                }
            }


        }
```

The specific implementation of each comment defined above:

```
        static void MyCommand(string input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MyCommand has been executed by the input '{input}'");
        }

        static void PrintHelp(string input)
        {
            // Unless the input that got us here is 'help', display the (wrong) command that was
            // entered that got us here
            if (input?.ToLowerInvariant() != "help")
            {
                // Display the wrong command
                Console.WriteLine($"Command '{input}' not recognized. See below for valid commands");
            }

            // Loop through each command from a list sorted by the HelpSortOrder
            foreach (ReplCommand c in _commands.Values.OrderBy(o => o.HelpSortOrder))
            {
                // Print the command and its associated HelpText
                Console.WriteLine($"{c.Command}:\t{c.HelpText}");
            }
        }

        static void Quit(string input)
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is a link to the [complete Program.cs file](https://github.com/igalnassi/ConsoleTestStaticPerformance/blob/master/Program.cs).

I have uploaded the complete codebase into my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/igalnassi/ConsoleTestStaticPerformance).

Comment: Nice idea using the Dictionary, I am still new to them (and basically everything). I believe I will try using some of what the user Leo posted as an answer, but if you could post an example of what you mentioned, that would be great as well. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @NathanialLake, First of all, congratulations in getting started. I have updated my answer with the code snippets and a link to my GitHub repo that contains a fully working example. Feel free to ask for any clarification you may need and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I normally try refacorting in such cases until I'm satisfied

> repeated EVERY time I ask for User Input and then check it

Then start by wrapping that in a function/method so you only have to maintain it in one place

```
private void ProcessInput(string input)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) throw new ArgumentException();

    input = input.Trim().ToLower();

    if(input == "exit" || input == "leave")
    {
        Console.Clear();
        ExitProgram.ExitProg();
        calcInput = false;
    }
    else if(input == "back" || input == "menu")
    {
        TxtFun.CTxt("Returning to previous menu.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        calcInput = false;
        calcLoop = false;
    }
    else
    {
        TxtFun.CTxt("Invalid input.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        calcInput = false;
    }    
}
```

Then refactor each `if` blocks...

```
private void ProcessExitInput(string input)
{
    if(input == "exit" || input == "leave")
    {
        Console.Clear();
        ExitProgram.ExitProg();
        calcInput = false;
    }
}

private void ProcessMenuInput(string input)
{
    if(input == "back" || input == "menu")
    {
        TxtFun.CTxt("Returning to previous menu.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        calcInput = false;
        calcLoop = false;
    }
}

private void ProcessDefaultInput(string input)
{
    if(input != "back" && input != "menu" && input != "exit" && input != "leave")
    {
        TxtFun.CTxt("Returning to previous menu.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        calcInput = false;
        calcLoop = false;
    }
}
```

Now your `ProcessInput` method becomes even smaller...

```
private void ProcessInput(string input)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) throw new ArgumentException();

    input = input.Trim().ToLower();

    ProcessExitInput(input);
    ProcessMenuInput(input);
    ProcessDefaultInput(input);
}
```

You can even use a `switch`/`case` block instead of an `if`/`else` block. Or even refactor the `if` conditions to a separate object...

```
class InputHandler
{
    public static bool IsExitInput(string input)
    {
        return input == "exit" || input == "leave";
    }
}
```

You can also create an `InputFactory` object that returns a specific `IInputProcessor` interface implementation based a specific criteria (`input`). Something like...

```
public interface IInputProcessor
{
    void Process();
}

public class ExitInputProcessor : IInputProcessor
{

    public void Process()
    {
        //process the exit command input
    }

}
```

And craft an `InputFactory` object to return the required implementation based on the current input

You can do whatever helps you organize and maintain that code later and there's no absolute answer to how you should write it. 
One hint, test-driven development normally helps write clearer and maintainable code

Comment: Thank you Leo! I am a self taught beginner and this post was very helpful. Cheers!